linux incorrect lvm disk size
I have 3 LVM disks in the system, and they are of different sizes. While the sizes appear normal in lsblk, when I check with the df -h command, the sizes of all three disks appear to be the same. It’s as if the disks have adjusted their sizes based on another disk. I’ve tried commands like resize2fs, but the issue wasn’t resolved. Could the LVMs have an incorrect mapper configuration? How can I check this

so come on, show us your df and lsblk or lvs or however else you're observing sizes that differ

df shows nothing about the PVs or the VG(s). And no one knows how you created your LVs, let alone your filesystems.

Note that df reports on (mounted ) file systems not on the size of the underlying block devices.
Especially after using LVM to resize a volume it is very common that people forget to resize their file system, a required step to be able to actually utilize the increased LVM size and see that increase with df.

Yes, I already know this; it’s also available on ServerFault. The resizing operations with LVM have already been completed. Outputs of commands like lvs, lvdisplay, pvdisplay, and pvs have all been checked. The issue is that in the df section, two LVM disks are showing the information of the third disk, even though the mappers are different.

@Dr.X What are you even referring to when you say "LVM disks"? Your PVs are added to VG(s) which is essentially pool(s) of storage that you can allocate to LVs. And as everyone said, df doesn't exactly tell anything about the LVs (let alone the VGs and PVs). And what "information" are you talking about? Can't you edit your post and add the df output there?
